# Can't start google chrome by selenium in Ubuntu

Tags: java, maven, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run an automatic test using selenium + jetkins on Ubuntu.
But when I run the mvn test command, I get the following error:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:  unknown error: Chrome failed
>   to start: exited abnormally   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file
>   doesn't exist)   (The process started from chrome location
>   /opt/google/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming
>   that Chrome has crashed.)

I looked at similar topics and decided that the problem is due to permissions.
Following the instructions from old topics, I added the following options to ChromeDriver

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        ...
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
```

But it did not help. What else is worth trying to fix the error?

Comment: Do you have the ability to run the tests locally? It may be a Jenkins issue.

Comment: just tried. same error when starting manually.

Comment: were you running your IDE as Administrator / Super User?

Comment: Yes i use 'sudo'